# aligning the name<p align="left">

Tags: php, html, alignment

i wanted to align my Welcome note to the right by using `<p align="right">`
but it doesnt seem to work..is it because Session/PHP doesnt work with p align?

```
<?php

    session_start();
 if($_SESSION['SESS_admin'] == 0)
  require("do_menu.php");
 else
  require("do_menu3.php");
 require("auth.php");
    require("do_html_header.php");
 do_html_header();
 print"<p align=\"RIGHT\"><h1>Welcome ". $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME']."!</h1></p>";
 do_menu();

?>
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: do you get any error or it is just not aligned?

Comment: http://www.webdesignerforum.co.uk/topic/4067-is-it-possible-to-place-a-header-tag-within-a-paragraph/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
 echo "<div style='text-align:right'><h1>Welcome ". $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME']."!</h1></div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because your `<h1>` tag is not set to align right and is instead set to align center. You need to override this with CSS. Try this instead: `echo "<h1 style="text-align: right;">Welcome ".$_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME']."</h1>"`

Answer (score 0):

```
 print"<p align=\"RIGHT\"><h1>Welcome ". $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME']."!</h1></p>";
```

You're allowed to use single qoutes, too. It might help you here.

```
echo '<p align="right"><h1>Welcome '. $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] .'!</h1></p>';
```

Also, print should have a space after it, or you should be wrapping what's being printed in parenthesis.

Edit: I used `echo` out of habit, sorry. You can use either, but I [think] I read somewhere that `echo` is a better choice than `print` - not 100% sure, though, but they do the same thing. I'll go look it up,  though. (Of course, if anyone reading this knows if one is better than the other, let me know!)

Answer (score 0):

The use of ALIGN is deprecated, and fails in many situations. In your case, you're probably writing something in the html_header.php which causes ALIGN to fail.

Try doing:

```
print "<div style=\"float:right\"><p><h1>Welcome ". $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME']."!</h1></p></div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div align =right>
<?php
..
..
.. // code you want to align to the right
..
?>
</div>
```

This way you can align a particular segment of code to the right.
If later you want to align some other segment of code in the center.
Then you can use

This way you can align the different segments differently.

Comment: Well i posted the code, it is visible to me, but it requires 50 reputation i guess?

<div align =right>
<?php
..
..
.. // code you want to align to the right
..
?>
</div>

can you see it now?